# Obtain Value From Group-Object

Tags: powershell

Working off of a previous post of mine (here: [Remove Duplicate XML Nodes in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32913524/remove-duplicate-xml-nodes-in-powershell/32919423#32919423))

Here's my code:

```
#Load XML file into $catalogXML
[xml]$catalogXML = (Get-Content (C:\test.xml))

$softwareVersionsArray = $catalogXML.catalog.software
$softwareToBeInstalled = $softwareVersionsArray|Group-Object name|ForEach-Object {$_.Group[0]}
```

Here's my current output for $softwareToBeInstalled:

```
name            version        installer_location                      
----            -------        ------------------                      
MozillaFirefox  31.3.0        /Mozilla/Firefox/31.3.0.exe             
Arduino         7.8           /Arduino/7.8.exe                        
GoogleChrome    35.7          /Google/Chrome/35.7.msi
```

Using a For loop, I'd like to grab values from my group object ($softwareToBeInstalled) and place them into variables (such as $softwareName, $softwareVersion, etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a simple `foreach` loop on `$softwareToBeInstalled` array:

```
foreach ($soft in $softwareToBeInstalled) 
{
    $softwareName = $soft.name  
    $softwareVersion = $soft.version
    $softwareLocation = $soft.installer_location

    Write-Host "$softwareName $softwareVersion $softwareLocation"
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed! I couldn't find anything on how to extract the info from the group object. Thanks much!